# macOS change text when you copy it to clipboard

Tags: macos, replace, automation, applescript

I have some text

```
blah blah blah
this is a new line
blah blah blah
```

I want to be able to copy the above text, and when I paste it, I want it to look like this

```
blah blah blah<br>this is a new line<br>blah blah blah
```

How do you do this in macOS?  Automation? Applescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to create an Automator Service workflow, to which you can then bind a keyboard shortcut via System Preferences.  In the workflow, you can insert a **Run AppleScript** action, or a **Run Shell Script** action.  Delete any existing sample code, and insert one of the following (depending on which action you opt for):

#### AppleScript:

```
on run {input}
    set my text item delimiters to "<br>"
    return the input's paragraphs as text
end run
```

#### Shell Script *passing input* to stdin:

```
input="$(</dev/stdin)"
printf "${input//$'\n'/<br>}"
```

You'll want to tick the checkbox called ***Output replaces selected text***.  To choose what the workflow should receive, decide which out of two scenarios you envisage activating this service:

1. If the service should operate on text that you've highlighted, which then gets replaced by the modified output, choose ***Workflow receives: text***
2. If the service should operate on text that is stored on the clipboard, which then gets inserted into the document you're presently working on, choose ***Workflow receives: no input***.  Additionally, insert the action called **Get Contents of Clipboard** above the **Run AppleScript** or **Run Shell Script** action.

Save your service as whatever you would like it to appear as in the service menu.  Assign a keyboard shortcut (such as <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) through *System Preferences*.

Comment: could you please specify a concrete actions?

Comment: @Gargo I don’t understand what you mean. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: I mean step-by-step instructions. I have never worked with apple script and I really don't userstand how and what to do with your instructions

Answer (score 2):

another one :

```
set theText to "blah blah blah
this is a new line
blah blah blah"

set curTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set theText to every paragraph of theText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<br>"
set theText to theText as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to curTID

return theText
```

Answer (score 1):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* shows a way to manipulate the *text* how you've shown it in your OP:

```
set theText to "blah blah blah
this is a new line
blah blah blah"

set curTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {linefeed, return}
set theText to text items of theText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<br>"
set theText to theText as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to curTID

return theText
```

> Result:
> `"blah blah blah<br>this is a new line<br>blah blah blah"`

You can incorporate this into a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, if that is what you desire.

Comment: and? the question was about how to modify a copied text, not just "blah blah..."